# How to parse SOAP message into Jaxb classes

Tags: java, soap, jaxb

I have a SOAPMessage Object.  I would like to parse and convert it into a set of Jaxb classes.
How would I convert the message into a format that Jaxb can unmarshal?

javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller.unmarshal(??)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The body of the SOAP message contains the actual data and its the bit you want to unmarshal.  You could do the following:

```
Node node = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();
unmarshaller.unmarshal(node)(
```