# Getting Request parameters from Spring WS Interceptor

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, spring-ws

I am using Jaxb 2 with a Spring WS, and I have an interceptor which is directed to a particular payload and it works fine.

Here my requirement is to read the request parameters from the handleRequest method of my interceptor. I know this should be fairly straight forward. However could not figure out a way to read the request parameters. At the moment my handleRequest method looks as below.

```
@Override
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint)
    throws Exception {

    boolean proceed = true;

    SaajSoapMessage saajSoapMessage = 
                    (SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest();

    SOAPMessage soapMessage = saajSoapMessage.getSaajMessage();

    Document doc = saajSoapMessage.getDocument();

    Element element = doc.getElementById("request");
}
```

The relevant part of the my Endpoint class is

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE, localPart = "confirOrderRequest")
public @ResponsePayload ConfirmOrderResponse handleConfirmOrder(
    @RequestPayload ConfirmOrderRequest confirmOrderRequest) {

     ...........
}
```

Here my requirement is to get the orderId which comes with the `ConfirmOrderRequest` in the interceptor handleRequest method, is there a way to do this directly, or do I need to do some XML parsing for that?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735583/how-to-parse-soap-message-into-jaxb-classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@VitualTroll, It helped me somewhat, thanks !

But answer on that question is incorrect(at least in my case). Body of my new  `handleRequest()` method would looks as follows. Hope this would save some time for someone else in future. Here jaxb2Marshaller is my spring bean.

```
  @Autowired
  private Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller;

  @Override
  public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {

    boolean proceed = true;

    SaajSoapMessage saajSoapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest();


    SoapBody requestBody = saajSoapMessage.getSoapBody();
    Object obj = jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(requestBody.getPayloadSource());


    if (obj instanceof ConfirmOrderRequest ) {
      ConfirmOrderRequest cor = (ConfirmOrderRequest ) obj;

      String orderId = cor.getOrderId();

      ...........
      .......
    }
  .....
 }
```