# Getting a particular field in soap body in org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

Is there any way to get a particular field value in a SoapMessage which is built from an XML file.

## Here is my incoming soap message,

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap:Header>
<wsa:Action xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://www.example.com</wsa:Action>
<wsa:MessageID xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">8d6f49b9-22c6-41d9-a1fb-bc07c82pbhar</wsa:MessageID>
<wsa:From xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<Address xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://bcd.com</Address>
</wsa:From>
<wsa:ReplyTo xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<Address xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://blah.com</Address>
</wsa:ReplyTo>
<wsa:To xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">https://blah2.com</wsa:To>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body wsu:Id="id-8" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<ns2:abc xmlns:ns2="abc" xmlns:ns3="abc" xmlns:ns4="abc">
<ns2:FunctionCallIdentifier>https://bcd.com</ns2:FunctionCallIdentifier>
<ns2:ValidityPeriod>120000</ns2:ValidityPeriod>
<ns2:fieldOne>
<ns2:Subfield xsi:type="ns2:MSId_AliasType" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ns2:property1>IWantToGetThis</ns2:property1>
</ns2:Subfield>
</ns2:abc>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now, I want to get the "property1" file, how do I do that, all I can see is getHeaders(), getContextualProperty(),etc, etc

Thanks!

Comment: How did you get this incoming request message at the server request?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link can help you:

[How to parse SOAP message into Jaxb classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735583/how-to-parse-soap-message-into-jaxb-classes)

Jaxb is framework for processing XML documents, as sopa body is a XML, you can process it with  Jaxb

Comment: Hi Alvaro, thank you for the response. I link you sent was actually using SOAPMessage which is javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage, but I need SoapMessage from org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage. I using it with WSS4J interceptors and need to access the SoapMessage body.Thanks